# Ableton Live Preset Resetting to Default

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live

So I've been playing around and came across a nice pad call Pad-A Snow Pad. You'll find this in 'Instrument Rack -> Synth Pad'. It'll be near the top, or should be. I don't know what I did but something has changed and I want to reset it to how it was before. Now it's just a long chord without all the nice bells and pulsating parts. Can someone screen shot a picture of all their settings as I'm clueless on what I may have deleted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I checked the Preset in Ableton and I figured something out. The Volume of the Starshower chain (the second row) which creates the bell sound is based on the Velocity. Just click on Vel above the chains (where mute, solo, pan... for each chain is located) to display the settings. Currently it is set to Hide (orange background). If you play a note with a velocity greater than 90 you won't hear the bell sound; you'll only hear the chord. If you play the notes with your computer keyboard, you can change the velocity with the keys "c" and "v" by default. By pressing "c" several times, you will be able to here the bell sound again. Your current velocity will be displayed in the long bar at the bottom of your display.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps or if anything is missing

[image: Part one of patch settings]

[image: Part two of patch settings]

Answer (score 0):

Also- unless you have changed the default preset and actually gone as far as to save it under the original name of the default preset, I'm pretty sure you will be able to access the preset in its original form if you were to restart ableton. Perhaps you might have to do this in another project if you were pressing save in the original project file--on that I'm not so sure.